# Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino'

Tags: python, linux, arduino, operating-system, ros

I have been using this ros kinetic ubuntu 16.04 . when i run the command
`rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0[enter image description here][1]`
I get an error stating

'[ERROR] [1634579585.317768]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino'

Can anyone give me a solution for the problem i encounter?

Tried it with uno and nano as well but still i get the error

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to rebuild `ros_lib` for your specific version of ROS. To do this simply navigate to where you have `ros_lib` installed and run

```
rm -rf ros_lib
rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .
```

This will rebuild the package for your current version.

Comment: I tried this as well but still i encounter the same error.